# Ansible: prevent 'changed' when looping

Tags: ansible

I like this pattern in Ansible:

```
tasks:
  - name: install packages
    apt:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600
      state: latest
    with_items:
      - build-essential
      - git
      - libjpeg-dev
```

However, I get a changed notification every time, even though nothing has been installed. I don't want to set `changed_when: False`. Is there a way to get the proper changed status from this loop?

**Update** If anything was installed by apt, I want changed to be True. If everything was already installed, and apt did not do any work when looping over this list, then I want changed to be False.

I'm using Ansible 2.0.1.0.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "get the proper changed status"?

Comment: What ansible version are you using?  I am guessing you're getting changed every time b/c you are specifying update_cache: yes

Comment: @Petro026 That was it. Write it up in an answer if you like, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changed indication is due the apt cache (apt-get update) being executed each time the task is run. If you only want an indication of whether packages were installed then remove the update_cache: yes directive or set to update_cache: no.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what it should be, after applying the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774877/456550) by @Petro026.

```
tasks:
  - name: install packages
    apt:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: latest
    with_items:
      - build-essential
      - git
      - libjpeg-dev
```